# sqlite3 update multiple recorders

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing a program in C, communicating with a SQLite3 db.

I'm trying to figure out how to update multiple records at the same time.

here is my SQL syntax:

```
UPDATE fieldTrip SET exit_status=1 where id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11;
```

How can I have id's 1 thru 11 updated with exit_status= 1 without having to do a for loop and doing 11 different update statements for each record. I understand that i can do "OR" in here but is that the right way that I shoudl be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `id`s in your `WHERE` clause are consecutive, how about using

```
UPDATE fieldTrip
SET exit_status=1
WHERE id>=1 AND id<=11;
```

EDIT (in response to OP's comment):

You could use this kind of construction:

```
UPDATE fieldTrip
SET exit_status=1
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ...);
```